# Get response from FlightStats SchedulesConnectionsService

Tags: xml, api

I have included FlightStats SchedulesConnectionsService.wsdl as web refrence in my .Net application but don't know hot to get response from web service as XML

Does any one have any idea , here is the link for Serivce

https://www.flightstats.com/developers/bin/view/Web+Services/SchedulesConnectionsService

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

helpdesk@flightstats.com is your best bet.